# Re-save a txt file using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to re-save, without modifications, a txt file using vba excel. Right now, the method that I'm using is to copy the content and then rewrite it, but that generates a blank last line. Can you help me?

```
myTxt = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files,*.txt", , , , True)
filecount = UBound(myTxt)


If filecount = 0 Then MsgBox "No text file selected. Exiting now.", _
vbExclamation: Exit Sub

For n = LBound(myTxt) To filecount
    Open myTxt(n) For Binary As #1
    FileContent = Input(LOF(1), 1)
    Close #1

    Open myTxt(n) For Output As #1
        Print #1, FileContent
    Close #1
Next n
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the point of this? You want to read the contents of a file and then write it back (to the same file)? Anyway, to avoid adding a blank line at the end of the file, use `Print #1, FileContent;` instead (notice the semicolon).

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Yes, that answer my question. Thank you a lot !